# Exporting and distributing a Java project using NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

First of all I'd like to mention I am not sure if I should be posting it here, but I just don't know any other places where I can ask this question.

I also know this question has been asked several times and there are several answers and guides out there, but believe me I tried them all.

I have made a Java project using NetBeans, I have all of my (4) classes in one package called "vanguard" and I even put my images' folder within that package. The project runs perfectly on my PC (no matter where I run it from, as long as it's on my PC) I am using a dynamic and proper way to load images, all works fine.

Once I clean & build my project, as you know the JAR file is created in the dist directory within the project folder. I've tried sending that mere file alone to other computers, I tried sending the whole project folder, all of it. Either way I keep getting the same result, once I press on the JAR file twice, a small window saying "A Java Exception Has Occurred".

My question to you is.. what am I doing wrong? How do I export my project properly for it to work on other computers? If you want to see my code just let me know and I'll post links to it, although I can only post 2, I think.

EDIT: I am receiving no errors on my own computer when running the project.
However, on different computers I receive as I said, an exception.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses. Also post the full exception and stack trace

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wish I knew how. I'm kinda new to Java and NetBeans.

Comment: Do you use any external libraries? Is there lib folder in your dist folder?

Comment: From the command line run the jar file, using something like `java -jar JarName.jar`, if an exception is been generated, then it will be printed to the console

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll do that right away, I'll post the results in a second.

And Kiki I don't and there isn't.

Comment: @MadProgrammer using your way it didn't work, I found a way online, here's what I used 
java -classpath Vanguard_Prototype_v0.1.jar vanguard.Main

Comment: Okay, that suggests that you've not configured the netbeans project to specify the main class for the jar file.

Comment: @MadProgrammer it said "jar" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sounds like the file associate between .jar and java isn't setup properly

Comment: I'll search the web and see how to set it up. I'll leave a message once I'm done or if I cannot do it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer been following this guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#Check
but half way through the guide, I got stuck. So I can't really set up the JDK or whatever.  I reinstalled Java and the JDK. In the guide, when I got to the "Installing the JDK Silently" part, about halfway through the webpage, I tried running the commands but nothing worked.

Perhaps you got a proper guide for me?

Comment: @MadProgrammer alright, I fixed it all except for what I asked in the first place. java is set up. Everything is set up. I ran the file and as you said the main class wasn't specified. How do I specify it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer ignore my previous message!! I ran it wrongly in cmd. I wrote "java jarName.java" instead of "java -jar jarName.java" it ran properly this time! However.. it still does not run on other computers so we've not solved my issue yet. :/

Comment: Do you have the same Java version on all computers ? What is the taget version of the compilation ? What is the version of Java on non-running computers ?

Comment: @PeterMmm I have the latest Java version on my computer and the latest JDK. (On the development computer) on the other ones, not sure if the latest Java. Since I sent it to friends via Skype, didn't get to check it. I'll check it right away and let you know what their version is.

Comment: @PeterMmm it works. Thank you both for the help. I really appreciate it!